# How can I trigger the dial's timeout

Tags: go, tcp, network-programming

I am learning networking with Go.

I wrote the code because I wanted to test the timeout of the current dial, but it doesn't work as I intended.

```golang
package socket

import (
    "net"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestDialTimeout(t *testing.T) {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")

    go func() {
        for {
            conn, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                t.Error(err)
            }
            t.Logf("[server] connection success from %q", conn.RemoteAddr())
            done := make(chan struct{})
            go func(conn net.Conn) {
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
                conn.Close()
                done <- struct{}{}
            }(conn)
            <-done
        }
    }()

    front, err := net.Dial("tcp", listener.Addr().String())
    t.Logf("[front] connection request from %q to %q", front.LocalAddr(), front.RemoteAddr())
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    t.Logf("[front] connection success to %q", front.RemoteAddr())

    dialer := net.Dialer{Timeout: time.Second * 5}
    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", listener.Addr().String())
    t.Logf("[conn] connection request from %q to %q", conn.LocalAddr(), conn.RemoteAddr())
    if err == nil {
        conn.Close()
        t.Error("connection did not time out")
    }
    t.Logf("[conn] connection success to %q", conn.RemoteAddr())

    nErr, ok := err.(net.Error)
    if !ok {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    if !nErr.Timeout() {
        t.Fatal("error is not a timeout")
    }

    listener.Close()
}
```

Since the server first connects with one client, I think that a timeout should be taken for the next client to be connected.

But printed message is below.

```
=== RUN   TestDialTimeout
    timeout_test.go:18: [server] connection success from "127.0.0.1:58517"
    timeout_test.go:30: [front] connection request from "127.0.0.1:58517" to "127.0.0.1:58516"
    timeout_test.go:34: [front] connection success to "127.0.0.1:58516"
    timeout_test.go:38: [conn] connection request from "127.0.0.1:58518" to "127.0.0.1:58516"
    timeout_test.go:41: connection did not time out
    timeout_test.go:43: [conn] connection success to "127.0.0.1:58516"
    timeout_test.go:47: <nil>
--- FAIL: TestDialTimeout (0.00s)

FAIL
```

No error occurs on the second dial.

Even the `time.Sleep()` doesn't seem to work.

I don't know what I did wrong.

Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: Your test panics if the timeout occurs, because you try to access fields of `conn` and `conn == nil` if there is a timeout. You only get a timeout of the other side does not accept the connection and there is no other error (such as "connection refused"). Like trying to connect to an IP number on your local network that no machine is using.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt
I took your advice and made sure conn is nil if server don't accept requests from the client for a while if I don't set a timeout on the client.

However, as you can see in the code, I set a timeout of 5 seconds using the dialer, and the server blocks for 10 seconds after the first connection. However, timeout did not work, and in the log, even the second client's request was accepted by the server.

Why doesn't timeout work? Also, why are the results printed immediately when testing, as if time.sleep doesn't work?

Comment: You sleep after you have accepted the connection; that is pointless. But even if you just do `net.Listen` without accepting the connection, the OS will still accept it for you. At the OS level, on Unix, you could call `listen` with a backlog of 1 and have keep another connection active, but in Go you don't have control over the backlog size. You can probably only achieve a timeout by trying to connect to an IP number that is not assigned.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt

I honestly didn't get it right, but what you mean is that `listener.accept()` is not a function to receive a single connection? Now I know the second connection is being accepted, but I don't understand exactly how it works internally. What keywords should I search for to find related resources to understand these situations?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt


Official documentation says "Accept implements the Accept method in the Listener interface. It waits for the next call and returns a plain Conn." It does, but I don't understand that the OS accepts the connection.

Comment: This question and its answers provide some background. Go works the same way, except you don't have control over the "backlog" parameter to the `listen` call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073871/socket-programming-whats-the-difference-between-listen-and-accept

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt

Oh, my God!
I understand.
In the case of `listen()`, the port-bound and requested connection information is stored in the queue data structure. `accept()` receives the information when ready, creates a socket, and returns the descriptor of the socket.
Therefore, when the client succeeds in connecting, `listen()` accepts the connection and stores it in the queue.

Is it right?! thank you so much for your kind reply I think I gained a lot of knowledge thanks to you!